# PhoneGap NFC reader on Android detecting tag but not displaying content on screen

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, nfc

I am trying to develop a program using PhoneGap. I would like to scan and display the tag ID from a scanned card.

When the app is built and deployed through build.phonegap.com and comes into contact with a tag the device vibrates but nothing shown on screen. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
function ready() {

    function onNfc(nfcEvent) {

        var tag = nfcEvent.tag;
        var tagId = nfc.bytesToHexString(tag.id);
        navigator.notification.alert(tagId);
        var y=document.getElementById("rand");
        y.innerHTML = tagId;

    }

    function win() {
        console.log("Listening for NFC Tags");
    }

    function fail(error) {
        alert("Error adding NFC listener");
    }


    nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener(onNfc, win, fail);
}

function init() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', ready, false);
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Scan NFC</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" />
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-nfc-0.4.1.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
 <p>Please scan NFC tag</p>
 <p id="rand"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you `main.js` has the function `init` and so on.

well the only thing that you need is add after you file `main.js`  the call to function init

```js
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> init(); </script>
```